# Differences between Page.User.Identity vs Request.LogonUserIdentity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

What are the differences (behind the scenes) between Page.User.Identity and Request.LogonUserIdentity? Not the differences in type, name, etc but the differences in how they're implemented behind the scenes (i.e. one calls windows xxx api and the other calls asp.net xxx api...).

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question. Is there anything specfic you are looking for? LogonUserIdentity returns WindowsIdentity object for the current logged on user.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It depends on what mechanism you are using to authenticate users, and what settings you have for impersonation.

For example, under the VS development server, using Forms authentication, the standard SQL membership provider and the following code:

```
// m_LoggedIn is a Literal control on the page:
m_LoggedIn.Text = string.Format("<br />Page.User.Identity: {0} " + 
                                "<br />Request.LogonUserIdentity: {1}",
                                Page.User.Identity.Name, 
                                Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name);
```

I get the following output:

> Page.User.Identity: zhaph
>
> Request.LogonUserIdentity: [ComputerName]\Ben

The first line (Page.User.Identity) is the forms authentication account I've logged into the site with, the second line is the windows identity the request is running under - as I've not enabled impersonation, this is my windows logon as that's the account the web server is running under.

In terms of the API's, [HttpRequest.LogonUserIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.logonuseridentity.aspx) is calling into the WindowsIdentity class, which will always represent a **Windows user account**, while [Page.User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.user.aspx) is creating a object which implements IPrinciple, which allows you to represent a user using a number of different backing stores - for example the SQL database structure supplied by the MembershipProvider.